# Traverse a 3D building

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a drone which I would like to find the better way to traverse an `3D` buildings from start point to an end point, regarding some conditons:

1- the drone must pass throught all the possible aisles of the buildings at lest once and as few times as possible, i.e. the drone must cover all the environment;

2- the 3D building is already known (not a mapping case), so the drone doesn´t use any kind of sensor to perform this task.

Anyone knows the best `algorithm` to do this task?
I kown there are some grid-based (A*, D*) and some other sample-based like RRT.
And how can I feed the algorithm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277718/traverse-a-3d-building/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds similar to the [seven bridges of konigsberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg) problem.

So you'll have to convert your 3D map of the building into a [graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) before solving this, this step is probably the hardest part of this challenge and will depend on what type of representation your map is in. If it is a mesh then finding the [genus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) of it is probably a good start.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2017-12-10**:
Thanks for replying. Actually my map is a `Collada` file that built in an 3D model toll and exported to `gazebo simulator`. So  I have it in  `sdf` as well.